# why all columns are invalid after table rename?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I renamed a table and since, in evry 'select' I get the 'Invalid object name' for all columns.

I get from my select the output I need, but why I get an error too ?

this is my simple select...

```
SELECT [Importance]
      ,[Color]
      ,[NotificationName]
  FROM [dbo].[Alerts]
```

Comment: can you please post your query ?

Comment: Also - what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What was the original table name and what have you renamed it to ?

Comment: from Colors to Alerts

Comment: Are you using sql server ?

Comment: yes i am using sql server

Comment: And 'invalid object name' does not refer to anything? I'd suspect the [dbo]. What user did the rename and how?

Comment: Are you getting error messages when running the code, or squiggly lines and "errors" from IntelliSense when parsing the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're using SQL Server Management Studio. I suspect your query will run if you try it, it's just that the intellisense doesn't know that the table name has changed.

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to refresh the cache or alternatively `Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache`.

You need to do this every time you perform schema changes.

Comment: you mean to refreash the cash in my browser ?

Comment: no in SSMS. Execute `SELECT * FROM dbo.Alerts`, if it works despite the red underlines then the problem is definitely that you need to refresh intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Run below query to confirm that your table has been renamed and has the exact column names specified in your select query:

`select * from sys.all_columns where object_id = OBJECT_ID('Alerts')`

Alternatively you can execute below query to confirm that the `Alerts table` exists

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'Alerts'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Alerts exists'
END
```

Also make sure you are in the correct database, run below query to find out the database to which Alerts belong :

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
AND  TABLE_NAME = 'Alerts'
```

Once you got the database name add `USE DATABASENAME` at the beginning of your query or you can use `DATABASENAME.dbo.Alerts`.

Comment: I did it the table  exists

Comment: Are you in the correct database, try adding `USE DATABASENAME` in the beginning of your query. Check the output of second query to find the database.